# R: how to do ensemble method with numerical target class?

Tags: r

So, I want to try to do ensemble method for my data, but I think it is only works with categorical target class, I wonder how to do ensemble method to numerical target class, in here my target class is `mpg`, and here is my code

```
> auto_mpg <- read.csv("D:/War/dummy/auto-mpg.csv")
> head(auto_mpg)
  mpg cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration
1  18         8          307        130   3504         12.0
2  15         8          350        165   3693         11.5
3  18         8          318        150   3436         11.0
4  16         8          304        150   3433         12.0
5  17         8          302        140   3449         10.5
6  15         8          429        198   4341         10.0
  model.year origin car_name
1         70      1       49
2         70      1       36
3         70      1      231
4         70      1       14
5         70      1      161
6         70      1      141

> control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                          number = 10,
                          repeats = 3)
> seed <- 7
> metric <- "Accuracy"
> 
> # C5.0
> set.seed(seed)
> fit.c50 <- train(mpg~.,
                   data = auto_mpg,
                   method ="C5.0", 
                   metric = metric,
                   trControl = control)
Error: wrong model type for regression
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensemble method is about combining the predictions of multiple models. This can be done for both categorical and numeric outcomes.

`caret` is superseded. Now there is `tidymodels`. The package `stacks` allows you to do ensemble regression of numerical data. See [this tutorial](https://stacks.tidymodels.org/articles/basics.html) in which the numeric outcome of latency, the time of egg hatching is modelled.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I want to ask a question. Is workflow() same as pipeline() in python?

Comment: Yeah. They serve the same purpose: Apply a sequence of steps to the data. This is usually pre processing like scaling and fitting the model. Then, the workflow is executed on all CV resamples and then combined into a stack.

Comment: I see, thank you so much. It helps me for learn